# Difference between Absolute and Fixed Product Custom Option Price Type Magento

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me the difference between absolute and fixed product custom option pricing in Magento?

I have used fixed price before, but I am not able to understand the working of absolute pricing, it doesn't add in product price when I add the product to the cart.

Comment: checkout the demo https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html

Answer (score 1):

Found this nice explanaition:
"With Absolute Pricing for Magento Custom Options you can now add a one time / fixed price / one off charge / fee to your products via custom options, to give an example you supply and sell promotional gifts, pens, pencils, diaries, umbrellas etc, by adding a custom option with an absolute price you can now charge your customer(s) a one off / one time charge / fee such as tooling, silk screening, logo design service charge(s) and any and many others, even multiple one off charges per product." See more here: http://www.absolutepricing.com/

Also check the demo: http://demo.1702.absolutepricing.com/example.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed price means option price will exchange with actual price of product and if customer will increase qty this price will be multiply !

Absolute Price means  product price will stay same for example product price is 20$ and installation fees 15$ if you will increase number of products price of product 20$ will be calculated but fees 15$ will stay same (Absolute )!